# What does the "stretches" of database_authenticatable of devise mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I see in the config/initializers/devise.rb, there is a configuration called "config.stretches".

```
# ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
# For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 10. If
# using other encryptors, it sets how many times you want the password re-encrypted.

config.stretches = 10
```

I don't understand what does the `stretches` mean. It says it is the times I want the password "re-encrypted". Why and we the password will be re-encrypted? And why I should specify a "times"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is that it makes brute force dictionary attacks take longer.

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20210617082229/http://www.securityfocus.com/blogs/262) is written in reasonably plain English, and might give you a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: thanks for your answer. That post is a little difficult for me, that I still not understand, sorry. Why you say it can make the attacks take longer? If I reset it to 100, whhat will happen?

Comment: Then it'll require 10x more work to compute your password hashes. The point of this is that it's expensive to generate the password hash. When you just need 1 (like when someone logs in), then no big deal. You won't notice the extra time. You are trying to make it more annoying / impossible for someone to perform a dictionary attack in a reasonable amount of time. They need to generate lots of hashes, so the slower the better (for you, not them).

Comment: Wikipedia has a decent article on this topic. I don't believe that bcrypt is doing exactly this (I don't understand the bcrypt algorithm to any degree), but the idea is the same.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching

Comment: I know what you mean now. If the stretches is larger, the encrypted password will be harder to decrypt. If someone hacked my database, he could get my encrypted password. If my "stretches" is bigger, it will cost him much more time. But I can't set it a very big value, because when the normal web user logging in, it need to encript the password, that may be cost too much time and cpu. So, if my data is not important, or I believe my server is very safe, that I can set it as 1. Right? Thanks, @jdl

Comment: If you leave it at 10, you'll never notice the difference in time.

Comment: @Freewind - suppose you set it so it takes a quarter second to encrypt a password. The user pays that price once when logging in; an attacker may pay that price 10,000 times per password while trying to guess it.

Answer (score 2):

Though @jdl answer has been accepted but it really isn't in a plain English or in the one I'd understand any better. [This link helped me better understand about stretches](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Speed-up-your-unit-tests)

> This will increase performance dramatically if you use bcrypt and create a lot of users (e.g. if you use Factory Bot or Machinist). Key stretching is a method of improving the security of passwords at the expense of speed.

For deeper understanding you can checkout [key stretching on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching)